# Textures not showing up in downloaded `.blend` file from Sketchfab

Tags: texturing

This is my first foray into working with Blender, and to start off I'm trying to compose a simple static scene with a few pre-built character models sitting in a room.

I downloaded [this rigged model of a alien](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/grey-alien-rigged-81d21f43c9b5401994f10ac5c45f6c4b) from Sketchfab (clicked "Download 3D Model" in the lower-left right below the artist's name and selected "Original format (blend)"). However, after extracting the ZIP file and opening the `.blend` file in `source/`, the model appeared as a grey blob with no textures, despite the model *clearly* being textured in the web viewer on Sketchfab.

Following the instructions from other sources, I [set the viewport shading to "textured"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5283/79100) (which for some reason now seems to be labeled "look dev" in the latest version of Blender), and attempted to [load missing textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink) from the `textures/` folder in the extracted ZIP. Neither of these actions seemed to fix the problem for me. Additionally, I will note that my model does *not* appear pink, which as I've heard from other sources is the usual sign of missing textures. Rather, the model is simply a dull, untextured grey.

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong? I'm using Blender 2.8 (the latest version).

Comment: After watching a few tutorials on texturing, I think I've discovered at least *part* of the problem. For whatever reason, the materials used for the Alien's body had "Use Nodes" turned off in their properties, and were set to a pure white base color. The problem is, I have no idea how or why it ended up like that. I was able to fix the textures by re-enabling "Use Nodes" for each material and manually assigning the proper textures, but I'm hesitant to post that as an answer without knowing what actually caused the problem in the first place. Any ideas as to what happened?

Comment: Actually, I believe this might be a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/131034/79100 (though I can't mark it as such, as that question doesn't have any answers either).

Comment: Just posted an answer. Still can't close this question as a duplicate until that answer gets either upvoted or accepted, but as soon as I can I will.