# How can I see texture on my model besides in shading?

Tags: texturing

For some reason I can only see the texture in shading. How do I make it so I can see the texture regularly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Textures Not Showing in Viewport (Blender 2.8)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131034/textures-not-showing-in-viewport-blender-2-8)

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch render modes. Pick either lookdev, also known as material preview (second from right), or rendered preview (farthest right). See below (highlighted red):

[image: RenderMode]

Answer (score 0):

There are four types of Viewport Shading: Wireframe, Solid, Material Preview, and Rendered.
Textures are (initially) only visible in Material Preview and Rendered. I would say that that is exactly what those shading types are for. But, if you want to, it is possible to also see textures in Solid shading.

Of the four Viewport Shading icons (usually) in the top right corner, click on the Solid shaded icon (2nd one from the left, a solid white circle) and then click on the little downward pointing ">" icon on the right side of the four Viewport Shading icons. Now under Color you can select Texture.

[image]